# Discord cant get or send message in online python webs

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord, get

I want to send or receive a message to the discord server in a very simple way. But no matter what you do, from the servers that are constantly running (https://www.pythonanywhere.com or replit.com ) the messages I send are not sent or received. When I run it on my own computer with the same codes, everything works normally. What can I do about it, I'm waiting for your help

```
import requests
import json


def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'MTEwMzY1OTUzOTEyNDk5NDExMA.GlhdEF.HazWIDn0QsamllCTzzFBHkH5FGOzKcb0jig6Zw'        
    }
    
    r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages', headers=headers)
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        print(value)
        print("\nyes\n")  
    
retrieve_messages('1177500227402477611')
```

This is what i want to see:

```
{'id': '1177536727666147338', 'type': 0, 'content': 's', 'channel_id': '1177500227402477611', 'author': {'id': '1103659539124994110', 'username': 'Yersiz', 'avatar': '612fdaa186ec17ff540836192d39849f', 'discriminator': '9491', 'public_flags': 0, 'premium_type': 0, 'flags': 0, 'banner': None, 'accent_color': None, 'global_name': None, 'avatar_decoration_data': None, 'banner_color': None}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [], 'mentions': [], 'mention_roles': [], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timestamp': '2023-11-24T09:10:33.450000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 0, 'components': []}

yes

{'id': '1177536672796262460', 'type': 0, 'content': 'a', 'channel_id': '1177500227402477611', 'author': {'id': '1103659539124994110', 'username': 'Yersiz', 'avatar': '612fdaa186ec17ff540836192d39849f', 'discriminator': '9491', 'public_flags': 0, 'premium_type': 0, 'flags': 0, 'banner': None, 'accent_color': None, 'global_name': None, 'avatar_decoration_data': None, 'banner_color': None}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [], 'mentions': [], 'mention_roles': [], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timestamp': '2023-11-24T09:10:20.368000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 0, 'components': []}

yes

{'id': '1177500253038059600', 'type': 0, 'content': 'a', 'channel_id': '1177500227402477611', 'author': {'id': '1103659539124994110', 'username': 'Yersiz', 'avatar': '612fdaa186ec17ff540836192d39849f', 'discriminator': '9491', 'public_flags': 0, 'premium_type': 0, 'flags': 0, 'banner': None, 'accent_color': None, 'global_name': None, 'avatar_decoration_data': None, 'banner_color': None}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [], 'mentions': [], 'mention_roles': [], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timestamp': '2023-11-24T06:45:37.221000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 0, 'components': []}

yes
```

This is what i see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lamaninin/bugfixsz.py", line 17, in <module>
    retrieve_messages('1177500227402477611')
  File "/home/lamaninin/bugfixsz.py", line 12, in retrieve_messages
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

png1: [in pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne6rZ.png)
png2: [online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppks6.png)